# Adding max tx percent ERC20

Tags: erc-20, liquidity-provider

I can see that many ERC20 tokens that has recently launched has an "set max tx percent" before adding liq. What does it stand for?

Is it to stop bots to buy upp all tokens as soon as liq has ben added?

Let say I would like to provide 3 eth and 20 Quadtrillion of a ERC20 token as Liquidity. How do I add an max buy limit of 0,1 eth for the first 1-2 minutes of the launch?

Comment: i didn't see such thing, could you please refer to the sources?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your buy limit will be in ETH, but you can control your transfer rate for your ERC20 tokens because this is what your contract do.

Yes they add this control to avoid big movement. However, if you want to be more secure, every ERC20 transactions will be more expansive because you need to keep track of your In/Out transfers.

I can't help you for the last part you need to code your contract for that. But there is something to do with SSTORE and event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appricate it!